# What is "several means by which this can be achieved" in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

> The solution then is to change the materials system; several means by which this can be achieved without changing the parent materials are described in Chapter 4, section 4.1.

I have tried to comprehend the meaning of the clause after the semicolon, but I do not understand it clearly.

Comment: The meaning is "**Various ways** by which this can be achieved ... are described in Chapter 4."

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous different ways of changing the system without changing any of the inputs. You can find those ways in chapter 4 section 4.1.

It is improper to end a question with words like "by", "at", "with". People do it all the time in spoken language, but in formal writing it's poor form. So, spoken the sentence would be closer to:  "[There are] several means this [the system] can be achieved by".

Words in brackets added for clarity. Semicolons combine two things that could be sentences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *It is improper to end a question with words like "by", "at", "with"* Aside from this rule being dubious (or worse), there's not a question here - do you mean a relative clause? But the rewriting in the first paragraph is good.